# Htaccess mod_rewrite conditions and parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need some help regarding rewrite rules of .htaccess, and some of the regular expressions there.

i alredy have some rewrite rules definitions in htaccess, so if i call html file, it is executed as php.

all i need now is if i open in browser like:

http://mydomain.com/some-string/12345.html

to call file article.php?id=12345

(id value can only be integer)

if you can help he how to achieve this...

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Michiel answer:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)\/([0-9]*)\.html$ article.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will catch (lower-case letters and hyphens)/(numbers).html and redirect to article.php?id=numbers. i.e. this will now catch cars/13.html, mens-shorts/27.html, etc.

Comment: tnx, you where very close to solution i need: RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)\/([0-9]*)\.html$ article.php\/$2 [NC,L]  ones more thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^some-string\/([0-9]*)\.html$ article.php?id=$1
```

Comment: tnx, but "some-string" is changeable... it can be "car", "audio", "player", "door", etc...

Comment: I tend to add the [NC,L] flags to the end of my rules so that the htaccess file stops looking for other rules. @Michiel needs to put an escape before the period in the html extension (\.html)

Comment: @user198003: If it is car, you can just replace `some-string` by `car`. If it can be really anything, you might want to change it to `.*`.

Comment: @Dickie: Thanks, that is true. I forgot that.